# Functional inequality from Art of problem solving.

Tags: functional-inequalities

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be real valued function  such that  $f(0)=0$ and 
$f(x+y)\geq f(x)+y f(f(x))$. Find all such possible $f$.

When $ x=0$ then $ f(y)\ge 0$ for all $ y\in \mathbb R$
For all $ y\ge 0$ then choose $ x=-y$ we obtain $ f(0)=0\ge f(-y)+ yf(f(-y))$

Source:
 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h307863p1662619

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Did you read the solution given on the source?

Comment: That's just it. You have $ 0 \geq f(-y) + y f(f(-y)) \geq 0 + 0 = 0 $, so $ f(-y) = 0 $. Edit: Ah, missing the $ x > 0$ case.

Comment: Any idea how to proceed?